# Unable to Load SSL Module in IBM HTTP Server v8.5

Tags: apache, ssl, ibmhttpserver

Yesterday I was able to successfully install IBM HTTP Server, and everything was working great until I attempted to begin configuring the SSL settings.

When attempting to load the SSL module by adding the following to my **httpd.conf** file:

```
LoadModule ibm_ssl_module modules/mod_ibm_ssl.so
```

...the server will fail to start up, and I see the following in my **error_log**:

```
[Tue Feb 17 16:33:29 2015] [info] mod_unique_id: using ip addr <removed>
(20019)DSO load failed: SSL0166E: Failure attempting to load GSK library (libgsk8ssl_64.so), libgsk8ssl_64.so: cannot open sharedobject file: No such file or directory
Configuration Failed
```

I have confirmed that I have GSKit installed with the **gskver** command:

```
libgsk8ssl_64.so
============
@(#)CompanyName:      IBM Corporation
@(#)LegalTrademarks:  IBM
@(#)FileDescription:  IBM Global Security Toolkit
@(#)FileVersion:      8.0.50.34
@(#)InternalName:     gskssl
@(#)LegalCopyright:   Licensed Materials - Property of IBM GSKit 
                      (C) Copyright IBM Corp.1995, 2014 
                      All Rights Reserved. US Government Users 
                      Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure
                      restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM     Corp.
@(#)OriginalFilename: libgsk8ssl_64.so
@(#)ProductName:      gsk8g (GoldCoast Build) 140910
@(#)ProductVersion:   8.0.50.34
@(#)ProductInfo:      14/08/13.01:22:06.14/09/10.13:23:58
@(#)CMVCInfo:         gsk8g_140909/gsk8g_ssl gsk8g_140909/gsk8g_cms gsk8g_140909/gsk8g_support gsk8g_140731/gsk8g_pkg gsk8g_140909/gsk8g_acme gsk8g_140909/gsk8g_doc gsk8g_140909/gsk8g_ikm
```

No other modules seem to be causing any issues.  I'm at a bit of a loss as to what is causing this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the apachectl and envars scripts.  Especially envars.  Sometimes these scripts are modified for running third party modules.  The path for the GSKit libraries are typically set up in the envars script.

Comment: Thanks Marv!  I wasn't aware of the `apachectl` script.  Simply swapping that in place of using `httpd` to start up the server corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the shared library symbolic links were missing from /usr/lib and /usr/lib64.  If you (re)create these links, it may clear your problem.  I navigated to the library directory (/usr/lib64 in this case) and ran (as root):

for name in $(ls -1 /opt/IBM/WebSphere/HTTPServer85/gsk8/lib64); 
   do  ln -s /opt/IBM/WebSphere/HTTPServer85/gsk8/lib64/$name ./$name; 
done

Of course change the source directory to what ever your install standard is.  It created all the links necessary in my case.

A.